# why my code shows error in my r program, using if else function?

Tags: r

i try to write a program below. but it's not working.x is a positive value there is a condition if x is even then
if and for x is odd it is else. I am new in r programming:

```
gam<-function(x){

if as.numeric(x%%==0){
ans<- factorial((x/2)-1)
}
else
{
ans<-  factorial(x-1)/2^(x-1)*factorial((x/2)-(1/2))
}
return(ans)
}
```

can anyone please help me?

Comment: If you're typing this into the console, you need to have `else` on the same line as the preceding `}`, like: `} else {`

Comment: But actually, your problem is `x%%==0`. What do you mean by that? And it's typical to put your `if` logical test in parentheses, as in: `if (condition) { ... }`

Comment: There seem to be a few errors in your code, can you give an example of what you want the input of the function to be (what does x look like?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your problem is you have missed

```
 if (x%%2==0)
```

may be this is the thing you want:

```
gam<-function(x){

if (x%%2==0){
ans<- factorial((x/2)-1)
}else{
ans<-  factorial(x-1)/2^(x-1)*factorial((x/2)-(1/2))
}
return(ans)
}
```

just put gam(2) or gam(3) etc.

Comment: This answer is not useful because it does not explain what the errors are or how this fixes them.

Comment: i edited my answer... please see it